# Intellij idea specs2 test play framework in-memory database evolution in multiple withApplication

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework

I'm using specs2 to test my play application. However, I get across a strange problem.

Below is my testing code(just ignore the Chinese):

```
class ThrottlersTest extends PlaySpecification with AroundTimeout {
  type EE = ExecutionEnv

  val apiKey = ApiKey(99, "taobao.crm.members.get")

  trait ThrottlerContext extends WithApplication {
    implicit val ee: EE = ExecutionEnv.create(Arguments(), org.specs2.control.consoleLogging, "test")
    val throttlersRef = app.injector.instanceOf[InjectedThrottler].actor
  }

  "一个限速为10次每秒的限流器" should {
    "在接收到第一条消息的时候应该初始化自己，并且回复Passed" in new ThrottlerContext {
      await((throttlersRef ? apiKey).mapTo[Passed.type]) must equalTo(Passed)
    }

    "在一秒内发送11条消息时，前十条回复Passed，第11条回复Limited" in new ThrottlerContext {
      upTo(1 seconds) {
        for (i <- 1 to 10) {
          await((throttlersRef ? apiKey).mapTo[Passed.type]) must equalTo(Passed)
        }
        await((throttlersRef ? apiKey).mapTo[Limited]) must beAnInstanceOf[Limited]
      }
    }
  }
}

object ThrottlersTest {

  /**
   * 用来注入Throttler. 绑定关系见
   * @see modules.TopModule
   */
  case class InjectedThrottler @Inject()(@Named("throttlers") actor: ActorRef)

}
```

This piece of code runs correctly if I use `sbt test` in the console. However, if i use the default specs2 runner in intellij idea:
[image: intellij idea test runner]

It throws the exception as below:

```
play.api.db.evolutions.InconsistentDatabase: Database 'default' is in an inconsistent state![An evolution has not been applied properly. Please check the problem and resolve it manually before marking it as resolved.]
@6nl3m44fd: Database 'default' is in an inconsistent state!
    at play.api.db.evolutions.DatabaseEvolutions.checkEvolutionsState(EvolutionsApi.scala:269)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.DatabaseEvolutions.evolve(EvolutionsApi.scala:226)
```

There must be something wrong in execution in Intellij Idea. And the problem disappeared if I put just one `in new WithApplication` in the code.

I think there should be a way to fix this. Any advice for solution is quite appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Came across the same problem - could this be an error in the test runner in intellij?

Comment: I've solved it by switching to ScalaTest using a `OneAppPerSuite` trait.